# can not find .h when i archive ipa

Tags: ios, ipa

when i click product->archive，there is issue like below:

[image]

[image]

the same, the other framework 'PBTools' can not find the headers too.

when i run it in my iPhone or in simulator it is working. this issue just appear when i archive ipa.

how can i change the setting? why this happen?

my Header search paths below:
how can i change this?

[image]

Comment: please check file exist in your project bundle or not

Comment: Try clean and build again.

Comment: thanks for all your help, i found why this happen now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your *Project Settings* (specifically *Header Search Path*) is different for *Debug* and *Release* configurations.

You can verify this by doing *Build for Profiling*, which will also use the *Release* configuration.

Comment: i have upload my setting, how can i change it? thanks.

Comment: hi @trojanfoe, my means i am not sure what is the path need enter for this.

Comment: thanks for all your help, i found why this happen now.